# Why no call event when entering code blocks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, trace

I'm using Python's `sys.settrace` to trace through code execution for a program analysis task.

In contrast to what the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) states I do not see a call event being registered when entering a code block.

A sample tracer I'm using is below:

```
class BasicTracer(object):
    def __init__(self, fun):
        self.fun = fun
        self.result_acc = []
        self.orig_tracer = None

    def trace(self, frame, event, arg):
        self.result_acc.append((event, self.fun(frame)))
        return self.trace

    def setup(self):
        self.orig_tracer = sys.gettrace()
        sys.settrace(self.trace)

    def shutdown(self):
        sys.settrace(self.orig_tracer)

    def run(self, file_path):
        if not os.path.exists(file_path):
            with open('_instrumented.py', 'w') as f:
                f.write(file_path)
                file_path = '_instrumented.py'
        src = open(file_path, 'r').read()
        # compile, execute instrumented version
        namespace = {
            '__name__'      : '__main__',
            '__file__'      : file_path,
            '__builtins__'  : __builtins__,
        }
        compiled = compile(src, filename=file_path, mode='exec')
        self.frame_acc = []
        self.result_acc = []
        self.setup()
        exec(compiled, namespace)
        self.shutdown()
```

For example, consider the source code:

```
src = """
x = 1
while x < 3:
  x += 1
"""
```

I see the expected return event upon exiting the `while` body, but there is no call event when entering. Am I missing something here?

```
import inspect
tracer = BasicTracer(lambda x: inspect.getframeinfo(x).code_context)
tracer.run(src)
tracer.result_acc
[('call', ['x = 1\n']),
 ('line', ['x = 1\n']),
 ('line', ['while x < 3:\n']),
 ('line', ['  x += 1\n']),
 ('line', ['while x < 3:\n']),
 ('line', ['  x += 1\n']),
 ('line', ['while x < 3:\n']),
 ('return', ['while x < 3:\n']),
 ('call', ['    def shutdown(self):\n']),
 ('line', ['        sys.settrace(self.orig_tracer)\n'])]
```

I'm using Python 3.6.3 on Mac OSX, in case that is relevant.

Comment: For anyone seeing this later on: the `return` event shown is actually not a function of the while loop, but rather of the return of the `exec` called in `BasicTracer.run`. @user2357112 's response clarifies the `call` event confusion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs are poorly worded. They say a `'call'` event occurs when

> A function is called (or some other code block entered).

but "some other code block" is referring to anything with its own code *object* and associated scope, not blocks like `while`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a reason a `'return'` event would occur for these then? The phrasing in the docs is the same (`A function (or other code block) is about to return.`), which prompted some of this confusion for me.

Comment: Nevermind. I see what happened, the `return` is actually associated with the call to `exec` not the block itself. My examples were misleading me